# Problem Occurred in SQL Server Trigger For INSERT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a Trigger named "tr_forinsert" on a Table Called "Alarms" FOR INSERT, when the data is inserted in Alarm's table, Trigger executes and insert the same data in another table. In the beginning the Trigger worked fine without any issues, but now trigger is not working as expected. Another issue occurred due to Trigger is that Alarm's table is not accepting the data, when I execute the INSERT statement into Alarm table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_forinsert
on Alarm
for insert 
as
Begin


    Declare @Module tinyint
    Declare @Aid int
    Declare @Code int
    Declare @CodeTitle varchar(500)
    Declare @Reason smallint
    Declare @ReasonTitle varchar(500)
    Declare @State tinyint
    Declare @Rack tinyint
    Declare @Shelf tinyint
    Declare @Card tinyint
    Declare @StartTime Char(500)
    Declare @EndTime Char(500)
    Declare @Content Char(500)



    SELECT   top 1     @Module=dbo.Alarm.Module,@Aid=dbo.Alarm.Aid, @Code=dbo.Alarm.Code, @CodeTitle=dbo.Title.Content, @Reason=dbo.Alarm.Reason, @ReasonTitle=dbo.Reason.[Content],
                         @State=dbo.Alarm.State, @Rack=dbo.Alarm.Rack, @Shelf=dbo.Alarm.Shelf, @Card=dbo.Alarm.Card, @StartTime=dbo.Alarm.StartTime, @EndTime=dbo.Alarm.EndTime, @Content=dbo.Alarm.[Content]
FROM            dbo.Alarm LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Title ON dbo.Alarm.Code = dbo.Title.TitleType LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Reason ON dbo.Alarm.Reason = dbo.Reason.ReasonType order by StartTime Desc



    insert into [ALMSYS].[dbo].[ACCU_ALMS] Values (@Module, @Aid, @Code,@CodeTitle, @Reason,@ReasonTitle, 
                        @State,@Rack, @Shelf, @Card,@StartTime,@EndTime, @Content)



END
```

**EDIT**

Ok, now I have changed the trigger as per follow

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_forinsert
on Alarm
after insert
as
Begin


    insert into ACCU_ALMS (Module, Aid, Code, CodeTitle,  Reason, ReasonTitle, State, Rack, Shelf, Card, StartTime, EndTime, Content)


        SELECT      Alarm.Module,Alarm.Aid, Alarm.Code, Title.Content, Alarm.Reason, Reason.[Content],
                         Alarm.State, Alarm.Rack, Alarm.Shelf, Alarm.Card, Alarm.StartTime, Alarm.EndTime, Alarm.[Content]
        FROM            inserted Alarm , Title, Reason where Alarm.Code = Title.TitleType and Alarm.Reason = Reason.ReasonType order by EndTime DESC




END
```

The problem is that after executing this trigger, data is not inserted in the **Alarm**  table but when I drop this trigger and insert any data in **Alarm** table then it is inserted fine.

I am trying to connect to the remote SQL server which is running SQL Server 2000, through my Linux machine as per the requirement. I've tested this trigger SQL Server 2008 it works fine there but not on the remote system.

Comment: Your trigger **assumes** that an `INSERT` only contains one row; it shouldn't. An `INSERT` can contain 1+ rows (where + can theoretically be an infinite number) .You also don't say why your trigger isn't working as you expect, but I suspect that the prior comment is why. Also you should avoid referencing the schema name when referencing a column; doing so is deprecated and will cause your SQL to fail at some point in the future. Just use the table's (object's) alias/name.

Comment: Also, what does this question have to do with python, linux and pyodbc? There's nothing in your question to suggest they are relevant here at all.

Comment: Finally, I note you declare `@StartTime` and `@EndTime` as a `Char(500)`. I can't think of any (date)times that are exactly 500 characters in length, and what's wrong with the `date`/`time` datatypes?

Comment: @Larnu i have mentioned python, pyodbc and linux is because it is the part of the working environment.

Comment: i am using python + pyodbc + linux to execute and communicate with the sql server

Comment: i expect my trigger ..if Table 1 gets the new row inserted ... it should insert that same data in Table 2 ... just like creating replica of the data which is inserted

Comment: Just because you're using those tools for something *related* to your SQL Server instance doesn't mean it's relevant to the question (every question regarding SQL Server 2016- isn't tagged with `windows` for example, because that's what SQL Server had to run on). Based on your comment above, however, it seems that my first comment hit the nail on the head. The assumption that an `INSERT` only includes 1 row has come back to bite you. `inserted` can (and will) contain multiple rows. A trigger is fired **once per DML statement** not once per row affect in a DML statement.

Comment: You need to change your trigger to reference the `inserted` object as a table containing 1+ rows and remove all those variables (they won't be needed).

Comment: But you still haven't said what the problem is. Also, why have you reverted tosy tax from the 80's, and your code should Benin the question, not the comments.

Comment: Note - sql server 2000 has not been supported for years. 2008 is now also unsupported. Your trigger should work if what you posted is accurate. But you have not provided context. How are you testing this? Is it using an application you (or someone else) wrote? If so, the first thing to do is verify that the trigger works using SSMS and a hand-written insert statement. If that works correctly, then you have isolate the problem to the application you are using. If I had to guess, the application is not expecting the extra messages. Add "set nocount on" as the first statement in the trigger.